# what's the difference between exporting a database and copying a database in microsoft sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am using microsoft sql management studios to maintain a really large database. I want to make a backup version so that our developers can view data from the backup. I saw that there is a "Copy Database" option and an "Export Database" option in microsoft management studios. What are the differences between these?

The reason I ask is our database has a lot of important data and we want to have a way to view previous data (not just create a backup to restore the db)

Comment: Did you try them? And what do you mean by the last paragraph? A backup will obviously pull in all old data as well, as long as it is in the database.

Comment: Look closer....It is Copy Database and Export Data. The export data option allows you to very granular with what you want to export instead of the entire database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188664.aspx), copy database allows you to do the following :

- Pick a source and destination server.
- Select databases to move, copy or upgrade.
- Specify the file location for the databases.
- Create logins on the destination server.
- Copy additional supporting objects, jobs, user-defined stored procedures, and error messages.
- Schedule when to move or copy the databases.

In my own word, I would say that copy database allows you to easily move a database from an instance of SQL server to another one.

Export database save the database to a file in the OS file system (like a backup). You then can copy those files and import them whenever and wherever you want.

Comment: thanks. I was able to actually create another database and export all my tables to this new database