# Same tables with same data in different sql server instance in different pc

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

I have one pc as main database server which all clients are logging to main table. I have another two pcs lying around and I want to use them as backup servers. These backup servers will have data from main table in main database server. I am not sure how to achieve such process and really appreciate the help. My database server is microsoft sql express edition and incoming data are from apis in aspnet core. Usually, I will use Microsoft SQL Management Studio and extract data tier from table and import data tier in another pc with same table name.

> Main Database (Main PC) -> Second Backup Database (Second PC) and Third Backup Database (Third PC)

I have never done this before and I can't find the solution yet. I want to replicate table from Main PC in another two pc. Not replicate whole database in another pc. 
[image: May be this is the way.]

> I found that there is no replication feature in express edition. Any possible approach for this backup process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment you are going in wrong direction.

First of all you said

> I have another two pcs lying around and I want to use them as backup
>   servers.

`Backup server` does not mean "to replicate table from Main PC in another two pc. Not replicate whole database in another pc.", what can you do with the copy of 1 table if something happen to your main server?

`Backup server` should contain transactionally consistent copy of your database, only this way you can re-direct your applications to the `backup server` and they will be able to work with it in case of disaster with your main server. And this means you should `backup` your database on the main server and `restore` it on the backup server, `backup`/`restore` will provide you with transactionally consistent copy of `database`, and `bacpac` won't.

As you are on `Express Edition` and cannot use `SQL Server Agent` you can write 2 scripts to `backup` and `restore` and launch them using `sqlcmd`. To schedule it you can use `Windows scheduler`.

Your `backup` script can look like this:

```
backup database MyDB to disk = 'path-to-backup-file' with init;
```

And your restore script looks like this:

```
restore database MyDB from disk = 'path-to-backup-file'
with move 'MyDB' to 'db-copy-path\MyDB.mdf',
move 'MyDB_log' to 'db-copy-path\MyDB_log.ldf',
replace;
```

Your cmd command looks like this:

```
sqlcmd -S myServer\instanceName -i C:\myScript.sql –U login_name –P password
```

Here you pass your `backup` or `restore` command in the file `myScript.sql`

> my source address is 10.11.20.181 and port is 5001

This means that for execute your `backup` script you should use the following:

```
sqlcmd -S 10.11.20.181,5001 -i C:\myBackupScript.sql –U login_name –P password
```

Comment: it works. the only thing is that it takes me some time to understand what is  transactionally consistent. and it still confuses me. To make a decision on which method is better, I think i find two articles that give some explanation that is quite interesting, "https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-Database-dump-and-Database-Backup" and "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661526/whats-the-difference-between-exporting-a-database-and-copying-a-database-in-mic". technically, one is data dump and another is data backup.

Comment: You can read about transactional consistency here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39483451/how-are-azure-bacpac-backup-files-different-than-sql-server-bak-files

Answer (score 0):

- SQL Server doesn't allowed SQL Server agent also in Express edition.
- CREATE the linked server on your destination database to connect primary database.
- Schedule one Operating system scheduler to execute database script. In your database script you need to fetch new records from source database using linked server based on "Which are inserted or updated in last n minutes".
- check those data in your tables using LEFT JOIN. If not exist the insert into the table.

For better performance, Insert fetched data into the temp table, then use below query.

```
INSERT INTO your_table()
SELECT t.*
FROM #temp t
LEFT JOIN your_table y ON t.id = y.id
WHERE y.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested this solution that can fulfill my requirement with minimum steps. 
I copy powershell script from this [link](https://www.sqlshack.com/sqlpackage-exe-automate-sql-server-database-restoration-using-bacpac-with-powershell-or-batch-techniques/). 
I also install sqlpackage from microsoft.

```
.\SqlPackage.exe /a:Export /ssn:ServerName /sdn:TableName/tf:path-to-backup-folder\mybackup$(get-date -f dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-s).bacpac
```

and I created task scheduler in my backup pc to execute this script every 6hrs. and I have another script to import this data back to database inside backup pc every 12hrs and delete those bacpac after import. 
 One thing to consider using this method is how big is your database since I am exporting every data every six hours and if your database is huge, this would cause the performance issue & I don't know what will happen new rows are inserted or updated when executing this operation.

I am really not sure what kind of errors will occur in the long run.

Comment: 1. In your question you asked how to move one TABLE to another server, not the whole database. Your answer instead makes backup/restore, i.e. moves the whole database. /TargetDatabaseName -/sdn requires database name and NOT table name as you wrote. 2. If you want to use backup/restore, native BACKUP/RESTORE are simpler

Comment: Yes, what i want to do is just backup one table from main database across different pc. However, I don't know how to backup to my destination which have ip, port with username and password in the wifi network.

Comment: I find it much easier to import using Data-Tier application

Comment: >>>However, I don't know how to backup to my destination<<< And how did you backup to path-to-backup-folder? When you use native backup/restore commands you also point to "path-to-backup-folder"

Comment: can you show me example. my source address is 10.11.20.181 and port is 5001. my database is LogTracker-Dev. "BACKUP DATABASE 10.11.20.181.5001/LogTracker-Dev to Disk 'C:\DB\LOGTRACKER.BAK' GO"?? I still have username and password.